# How to do not select duplicated values from db?

Tags: python, sql, database, algorithm, postgresql

I have the following `comment` table(comment and corresponding info including photo_id)

```
comment_id | photo_id |  ... 
  com_1    | pho_1    |  ...
  com_2    | pho_2    |  ...
  com_3    | pho_1    |  ...
  com_4    | pho_2    |  ...
```

Frontend sends a request: "Hey, backend, give me info about first 2 items and I will display it"

Backend setup token to the `third` item:

```
 comment_id | photo_id |  ... 
   com_1    | pho_1    |  ...
   com_2    | pho_2    |  ...
-->com_3    | pho_1    |  ...
   com_4    | pho_2    |  ...
```

and select all info up to the third comment like this:

```
 pho_1      com_1 
 pho_2      com_2
```

and then add all other comments to corresponding photo_id's and send it to front, so the final info that user will see, will be:

```
pho_1      com_1, com_3
pho_2      com_2, com_4
```

I have the following problem: if front sends another request "Hey, backend, give me info about next 2 items and I will display it". Then backend again setup token to the `fifth` item and send exactly the same info to front, so the user will see exactly the same info, because

1) it select

```
 pho_1      com_3 
 pho_2      com_4
```

2) and append other comments to the photos id's, it will be:

```
pho_1      com_1, com_3
pho_2      com_2, com_4
```

How to avoid this and do not send duplicated info?

Comment: Do you have a Foreign Key on the photo_id?

Comment: @lbere yes, I have

Answer (score 0):

From the way i see it, you have 2 options.

**You *DO* have a Foreign Key on the Photo id**:

```
select * comment as c
right join (
    select * from photo 
    limit 2 offset 0
) as p
on c.photo_id = p.photo_id
```

---

**You *DO NOT* have a Foreign Key on the Photo id**:

```
select * comment 
where photo_id in (
    select photo_id from comment 
    limit 2 offset 0
)
```

In both, you need to page from the photo_id perspective.

Comment: I think that I will have the same problem

Comment: did you try it?